# Перманентно и навсегда - синонимы?

Tags: семантика, синонимы

Можно сказать:

> у него *вечно* полно гостей дома

или

> у него *перманентно* дома куча народу

**Или же:**

> *перманентная* блокировка аккаунта = блокировка аккаунта *навечно*

Т.е. хотя перманентность означает *непрерывное и бесконечное сохранение некоторого свойства*, но в некоторых контекстах является синонимом слова *навечно*.

Я прав?

Comment: Навечно или невечно? Надо бы определиться.

Comment: @shampar поправил

Answer (score 1):

Неправы. Перманентный – непрерывно продолжающийся, постоянный. Перманентная революция, перманентная война и т.п. Непрерывный процесс! А блокировка не есть процесс. Да и вообще – стоит ли изъясняться так вычурно?

А "перманентно куча народу" и вовсе звучит комично.

Comment: Перманентный — периодически повторяющийся, или постоянно возобновляющийся.

Comment: Откуда такое взяли?

Comment: *Откуда такое взяли?* - ну есть такое, перманентное встряхивание - это же периодический процесс? А вот "постоянный" я бы без уточнений у вас не принял. "Перманентный процесс" - разве всегда можно назвать постоянным? Как правило имеется в виду процесс *нарастающий*.

Comment: Впрочем, всё это не по сути вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Примеры ваши искусственны и не показательны. Но даже из их следует, что ни о какой синонимии тут речи нет.
"Всегда" и "навсегда" - разве это синонимы? 
Так вот, "перманентно" - это в книжном и научном стиле речи может значить "всегда", вернее сказать - "постоянно". Хотя и это не главное значение, главное - непрерывно (или непрерывно-периодически, на чем так настаивает shampar). Вне книжного стиля это слово вообще лучше не употреблять.

Ну а "навечно" - это и есть "навсегда".

Answer (score 1):

> т.е. хотя перманентность означает непрерывное и бесконечное сохранение
>   некоторого свойства, 
>   Нет. Сохранение в бесконечности - это всего лишь одно из свойств, которое может сопутствовать или не сопутствовать перманентности. 
>   "перманентная блокировка акаунта" - неудачный оборот. Он был бы правилен, если бы аккаунт какое-то время (не обязательно бесконечно) блокировался каждый день. А тут надо употребить слово **бессрочная**.
>
> в некоторых контекстах является синонимом слова невечно.

"Навечно" здесь подходит по смыслу потому, что "перманентно" употреблено не к месту.

Answer (score 1):

Что касается примера "**перманентно дома**", так сказать нельзя, поскольку перманентность предполагает как минимум, непрерывность состояния, а народ наверняка время от времени расходится.

"**Перманентная блокировка аккаунта**" - здесь другая проблема. Она состоит в том, что в русский слово "перманентный" попало лишь с парой своих иностранных значений: непрерывность и постоянство (революции, по Троцкому). В результате данное выражение оказывается калькой с английского (кто-нибудь из компьютерщиков его так перенёс), где оно совершенно нормально, причём наречие "перманентно" (permanently) вполне может означать "**навсегда**" (бесконечно долго) и даже "**необратимо**" (be permanently damaged - получить необратимые повреждения, о технике). Но в русском данное выражение остаётся непонятным из-за когда-то приписанных слову "перманентный" ограничивающих синонимов. Не исключено, что это когда-нибудь изменится. На мой взгляд, канцелярские изыски "*пожизненная (или вечная) блокировка*" гораздо хуже такой кальки (слово "бессрочная" верно было предложено).

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. Диссонанс был именно из-за того, что в английском значение данного слова (группы слов) шире. Теперь всё стало на свои места!